# TSConfig paths and "Unsafe call of an `any` typed value" on imports

Tags: typescript, eslint, monorepo, typescript-eslint, turborepo

I have a method in a service e.g. -

```
// file some-service.ts
export const getKey = (key: string) => key;
```

and use it as follows with import alias -

```
import * as someService from '~/shared/services/some-service';

// eslint reports on this line
someService.getKey('test');
```

ESLint reports on it -

```
Unsafe call of an `any` typed value. (eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call)
Unsafe member access .getKey on an `any` value. (eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access)
```

when i'm changing the path to be relative instead, TS doesn't complain -

```
import * as someService from '../../services/some-service';

someService.getKey('test');
```

Afaiu the issue is related to the way aliases like `~` are setup. The app is a monorepo with `tsconfig.json` in the root folder -

```json
{
  "extends": "tsconfig/base.json"
}
```

and also in the `./apps/my-app/tsconfig.json` -

```json
{
  "extends": "tsconfig/base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what exactly is missing in this setup, it would be great if each app could setup aliases by itself

- Typescript v4.8.4
- ESLint v8.56.0
- `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` v6.19.1

Comment: you are exporting the function, why not just import the function rather than the entire module?

Comment: @JorgeGuerreiro it still reports even when import just a func, the issue is in the aliases but it's not clear for me what exactly is the problem with them.